# NSTimer link with UIPickerView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, uipickerview, nstimer

I have a **UIPickerView** with an array in one view controller and an **NSTimer** in another, i am trying to:

1) link the picker array to **NSTimer** so a user selects a time on the picker for image to self destruct

2) show time remaining in **UILabel** so seconds the user selects going down to 0. *(ex. select 2 from picker label shows 2 then 1 then 0 and image destucts)*

```
one vc.h

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *timePicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pickerData;

one vc.m 

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.pickerData = @[@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7];

    self.timePicker.dataSource = self;
    self.timePicker.delegate = self;
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.textField setText:self.userText];
}

-(long)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

-(long)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return self.pickerData.count;
}


- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    [self.pickerData objectAtIndex:[self.timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
}


two vc.h

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int seconds;

two vc.m

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:7 target:self selector:@selector(timeout)
                                           userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.seconds target:self selector:@selector(setTimeToLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)timeout
{
 // pops to root view
}


- (void)setTimeToLabel
{  
    self.seconds = self.seconds - 1;
    self.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.seconds];
}
```

the **NSTimer** does not respond to the `self.seconds` and does not pick up the user input from the **UIPicker**.

any ideas as to how I can link the picker to the timer so that the timer responds to the seconds the user selects in the picker and display the remaining seconds in the label??

my prepareforsegue method below:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[oneViewController class]]) {
        oneViewController * ovc = (oneViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        ovc.array = //whatever;
    }

    if  ([segue.destinationViewController isEqual:@"secondVC"]) {
            NSInteger row = [self.timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
            twoViewController *tvc = [segue destinationViewController];
            tvc.seconds = [[self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row] intValue];
    }
}
```

what can be the issue with it, the onviewcontroller method works, whatever i pass it works, but for the tvc.seconds nothing is passed to it.

Comment: if you NSLog self.seconds in two viewDidAppear what do you get?

Comment: it displays 0 in the console

Comment: how pass user input value from one controller to other controller?

Comment: how do you mean? i have tried passing the value calling on the twoViewController then allocating and initialising it.

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved @smithyy?

Comment: @Scriptable not yet i am still looking for a way to resolve it. the second view controller is not connected via a segue to the first view controller so i think the prepare for segue methods might not work.

Comment: yeah that seems like it would cause an issue, have you tried it by adding a segue? is there a reason your not using a segue? If your manully moving to the second view controller this logic would need to be applied to the instance of the second view controller you are creating.

Comment: yes, when we select a time on the picker after we take a pic we move to a selectuservc via a segue then we send the information to parse. in the inbox we call on the second vc so it displays the image for that amount of time selected from the picker

Comment: so im using this method button in the **ibaction next** `ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNib:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
viewControllerB.isSomethingEnabled = YES;
[self pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];`

Comment: @Scriptable it still does not seem to work so any ideas?

Comment: set `viewControllerB.seconds` before this line `[self pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];`

Comment: the value being passed is still 0 i am not sure why the seconds are not passed to the second vc

Comment: what is the next ibAction attached to?

Comment: @Scriptable thanks for all your help over that past few days. i have managed to solve it after all this time. take care :)

Comment: what was it? good to hear you sorted it out, take care

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new instance of the controller rather than the actual one that would be used. You should be using the `prepareForSegue` method to do this, and get a reference to the destinationViewController, like so:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqual: @"nextScreen"]) {
        NSInteger row = [self.timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
        SecondViewController *tvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        tvc.seconds = [[self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row] intValue];
    }
}

// First View Controller
//.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *timePicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pickerData;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *next;

@end

//.m
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.pickerData = @[@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7];

    self.timePicker.dataSource = self;
    self.timePicker.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return self.pickerData.count;
}

- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", self.pickerData[row]];
}


- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    [self.pickerData objectAtIndex:[self.timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqual: @"nextScreen"]) {
        NSInteger row = [self.timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
        SecondViewController *tvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        tvc.seconds = [[self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row] intValue];
    }
}

@end

// SecondViewController
//.h
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController : ViewController

@property (nonatomic) int seconds;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;

@end


//.m
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:7 target:self selector:@selector(timeout)
                                   userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.seconds target:self selector:@selector(setTimeToLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)timeout
{
    // pops to root view
}


- (void)setTimeToLabel
{
    self.seconds = self.seconds - 1;
    self.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.seconds];
}

@end
```